# Need to correct the way my app moves an image

Tags: ios, xcode

I need my app to move an image when the user clicks on a certain button. This works perfectly:

ViewController.m

```
#import "ndpViewController.h"

@interface ndpViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;

-(void)movetheball;

@end


@implementation ndpViewController

@synthesize image;
int ballx, bally;


-(void)movetheball {
[UIView beginAnimations: @"MovingTheBallAround" context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 1.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

image.frame =  CGRectMake(ballx,bally,image.frame.size.width,image.frame.size.height);

[UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   }


- (IBAction)calculatePush:(id)sender {
    ballx = 600; 
    bally = 800; 
    [self movetheball];
}
@end
```

But as soon as the app has to do something else (when user clicks the button), like adding a text to a label, which I do in this way:

```
 _lizfwLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",lizfw];
```

then the app will move the image only upon clicking the button a second time.

Any idea on why is this happening? Thank you!

Comment: have you added breakpoint to calculatePush to see weather you are calling calculatePush on each click of button.

Comment: Hi and thanks for taking the time to help me. I am new to iOs development so I am not sure that I understand what you mean. I guess I do call it everytime since all instructions (except moving the image) I place within it are executed on first click. If I only try to move the image (as per the code shown abovE) it works perfectly.

Comment: Inorder to debug the code we use breakpoint see this http://mobiledevelopertips.com/debugging/xcode-4-debug-breakpoints-conditions-actions-and-ignore.html . So Use the breakpoint in calculatePush method and debug the code. just add the breakpoint and run the application.

Comment: Yes, everytime I click the button the image move is called. If I add the new line changing the text of the label, then the image will not move until the second click.

Comment: I tried to do the same thing as you want and it is working fine for me. Can you post the code for method, which causes problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another one method to animate `UIView`'s in iOS. Apple advices to use `[UIView animate...]` rather then old style `[UIView begin/commitAnimations];`.

In your case you should replace `movetheball` method code to that one:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    CGRect frame = image.frame;
    frame.origin.x = ballx;
    frame.origin.y = bally;
    image.frame = frame;
} completion:nil];
```